# Return mini batch of items from generator

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to create a class that wraps a generator function, so that I can obtain items from the generator in batches of a predefined size.

I.e. if I had a list of 10 random numbers and specified a mini batch size of 2 I'd like to get 5 tuples of 2 numbers.

I wrote the following wrapper class to a generator function hoping it would do the job:

```
import random

class multiple_lottery_draws(object):
    def __init__(self, num_draws):
        self.num_draws = num_draws
        print("Initialized % draws"%self.num_draws)

    def my_lottery(self):
        # returns 9 numbers between 1 and 100
        for i in range(10):
            yield random.randint(1, 100)

        # returns a 10th number between 1000 and 2000
        yield random.randint(1000,2000)

    def __iter__(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(self.num_draws):
            data.append(next(iter(self.my_lottery())))
        yield data

two_draws = multiple_lottery_draws(2)
```

However, although the generator by itself works just fine,

```
for i in two_draws.my_lottery(): print i
# prints: 52,12,61,67,30,78,84,90,69,31,1069
```

if I try to obtain mini-batches from the wrapper class I only get 1 item

```
for i in two_draws: print i
# prints: [74, 95]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `yield` only once. Try something like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    data = []

    for i in self.my_lottery():
        data.append(i)

        if len(data) == self.num_draws:
            yield data
            data = []

    if data:
        yield data
```

Comment: Yep, this was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in `my_lottery`, you call `yield` 10 times (in the loop), and it yields 10 values.  But in `__iter__`, you only call `yield` once, and thus only yield  one batch of values.